# How to create java client using AXis 1.4 for consuming WCF service using wsHttpBinding

Tags: java, wcf, client, axis

I have created a java client for consuming WCF service using axis 1.4. If I use basicHttpBinding than everything works fine, but if I use wsHttpBinding than I am getting following error:-

```
Did not understand "MustUnderstand" header(s):{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}MustUnderstand
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: Did not understand &quot;MustUnderstand&quot; header(s):{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:96)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.tempuri.WSHttpBinding_IService1Stub.getData(WSHttpBinding_IService1Stub.java:171)
    at Mytes.main(Mytes.java:14)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:2207A-H7-SITA

Did not understand "MustUnderstand" header(s):{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:96)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.tempuri.WSHttpBinding_IService1Stub.getData(WSHttpBinding_IService1Stub.java:171)
    at Mytes.main(Mytes.java:14)
```

Pls let me know how can I resolve this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When you use Axis to generate proxy for a WCF service, it generates the  stub that automatically sets the `MustUnderstand` header for `http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing`

The code below  resets the MustUnderstand flag back to false. for the method being invoked. I had a similar issue today and was able to resolve using the code that's posted here

```
//maybe someother service stub,i show you a case
    CommentWcfServiceLocator locator =new CommentWcfServiceLocator();
    WSHttpBinding_ICommentServiceStub stub;
    try {       
    //get a stub and set service url
    stub = (WSHttpBinding_ICommentServiceStub)   locator.getWSHttpBinding_ICommentService(new         java.net.URL("http://www.google.com/CommentWcfService.svc"));

    // the key is here , importantest!!! follow this
    // set action, action path,you can find in your java code
    SOAPHeaderElement action = new SOAPHeaderElement(new QName("wsa:Action"),     "http://tempuri.org/ICommentService/GetCommentSummaryByHotelId");
    SOAPHeaderElement to = new SOAPHeaderElement(new QName("wsa:To"),
    stub._getProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY));
        action.setActor(null);
        action.setNamespaceURI("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
        to.setActor(null);
        to.setNamespaceURI("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
         // set header
                stub.setHeader(action);
        stub.setHeader(to);
                // must set this property
        stub._setProperty(Call.CHECK_MUST_UNDERSTAND, Boolean.FALSE);
            stub.getCommentSummaryByHotelId("","02201158", 0);
    } 
catch(Exception EX){}
```

I found the [this post](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/understand-famous-did-not-understand-mustunderstand-header-s-error/) on MustUnderstand veru helpful.

Comment: along with your answer, here's a very informative link as to why this should be done http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/understand-famous-did-not-understand-mustunderstand-header-s-error/

Answer (score -2):

BasicHttpBinding or webHttpBinidng (REST services) are the only option to interact with non-microsoft technologies.
BasicHttpBinding is only binding which supports the Basic Profile 1.1 for interoperability.

Please go through below links and see if they can help you out to understand basic and ws bidning.

http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/choosing-the-right-web-service-binding.aspx

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223065644/http://geekswithblogs.net/claeyskurt/archive/2008/04/22/121508.aspx)

Comment: Ws-security is not a Microsoft technology, and it's definitely possible to consume a WCF service that uses a wsHttpBinding

Comment: the answer above explains how you could tweak the axis client and make it work wsHttp binding